# Arraylist of Objects not getting sorted or swaped

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop, arraylist

I want to sort the objects, and I have applied the approach two ways, however none works. When printing the the content of the arraylist, the elements are in the order they were inserted, and not lexicographically sorted.

I did do research within stackoverlow:

1. [Sort ArrayList of ArrayList of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546413/sort-arraylist-of-arraylist-of-objects)
2. [Sorting an ArrayList of objects (ArrayList not being changed after sorting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687606/sorting-an-arraylist-of-objects-arraylist-not-being-changed-after-sorting)

I did look into the `implements` approach where we make override `compareTo` function. But, those approach are not making sense to me. I wanted to make my `ArrayList` a private variable and all the examples I saw had the `ArrayList` in main class (I am new to OOP langauges too, and wanting to learn if someone is willing to give appropriate resources).

Any help or hint is appreciated.

**Main.java**

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int puedecCapacity = 0;
        
    String spa_nameString = null;

    Puedec puep = new Puedec();
    
    System.out.print("Enter 1st string to add: ");
        spa_nameString = scnr.next();
    puep.addPue(spa_nameString);
    
     System.out.print("Enter 2nd string to add: ");
        spa_nameString = scnr.next();
    puep.addPue(spa_nameString);
        
    System.out.print("Enter 3rd string to add: ");
        spa_nameString = scnr.next();
    puep.addPue(spa_nameString);    
        
    puep.sortPue();
    
    puep.printPue();
    
  }

}
```

**Puedec.java**

```java
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Puedec {
        
    private int Puedec_size;
    private int Puedec_size_fill_count;
    
    private ArrayList<Pue> pue_ArrayList = new ArrayList<Pue>(getCapacity());

    
    public Puedec() {
        
        this(3);
        
    }
    
    public Puedec(int capacity) {
        
        Puedec_size = capacity;
        
    }
    
    public int getSize() {
        
        return Puedec_size_fill_count;
        
    }
    
    public int getCapacity() {
        
        return Puedec_size;
        
    }

    public boolean addPue(String spa) {
        
        if(getSize() == getCapacity()) {
            
            System.out.println("Error");
            
            return false;
            
        }else {
            for(Pue p : pue_ArrayList) {
                
                if(p.getSpa().contains(spa)) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    
                    return false;
                }
                
            }
            
            
            pue_ArrayList.add(new Pue(spa)); 

            ++Puedec_size_fill_count;
            return true;
         }  
        
    }
    
    public void sortPue() {
        
        // This also not changing anything in the ArrayList
        /*
        pue_ArrayList.sort((pk1, pk2)
                     -> pk1.getSpa().compareTo(
                         pk2.getSpa())
                 );
        */
                
        
        int size = pue_ArrayList.size();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < pue_ArrayList.size() - 1; i++) {
            
            for(int j = 0; j < pue_ArrayList.size(); j++) {
                
                if(pue_ArrayList.get(i).getSpa().compareTo(pue_ArrayList.get(j).getSpa()) > 0) {
                    
                    Pue tempPue = pue_ArrayList.get(i);

                    pue_ArrayList.set(i, pue_ArrayList.get(j));
                    
                    pue_ArrayList.set(i, tempPue);
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public void printPue(){
         for(Pue pp : pue_ArrayList) {
            System.out.println(pp.getSpa());
        }
    }

}
```

**Pue.java**

```java
public class Pue {

    private String spa; 
    
    public Pue(String spa) {
        this.spa = spa;
    }

    public String getSpa() {
        return spa;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `public void sortPue() { pue_ArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pue::getSpa)); }`

Comment: Thank you @Bohemian! Works like a charm. I did have to make some adjustments though - but it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this code to your `sortPue()` method:

```
public void sortPue() {
    Collections.sort(pue_ArrayList,
        new Comparator<Pue>()
        {
            public int compare(Pue pp1, Pue pp2)
            {
                return pp1.getSpa().compareTo(pp2.getSpa());
            }        
        });
}
```

When implementing `Comparator`, you have to specify the types you want to compare, in this case there is `<Pue>`. Then, we have to add an implementation for the `compare` method, passing two object references to be compared. In the end, `String`'s `compareTo` method is used to sort the list.

`Collections.sort` takes 2 parameters:

- the list to be sorted;
- the comparator to determine the order of the list. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering should be used.

String `compareTo` returns:

- the value `0` if the argument string is equal to this string;
- a value `less than 0` if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument;
- a value `greater than 0` if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Comment: Hello! Appreciate your help. Unfortunately, after I make this code my sort() function, it just print backwards from last elements. For instance, if inputs are [Puepue, Chiro, Kaka] then after sort it prints  [ Kaka, Puepue, Chiro,]. I thought it should be  [Chiro,Kaka, Puepue]

Comment: Wait. Sorry, I confused myself. Thank you for a great explanation and your answer :)

Comment: no worries, glad it helped

Comment: To sort in descending order, something like this should work inside the `compare` method: `return pp2.getSpa().compareTo(pp1.getSpa());` . Sorry, made a mistake in a previous comment

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions in mind.

Since you said that when we override compareTo and etc. didn't make so much sense to you, I'll provide a really basic solution aswell after the most simple one.

**The most simple**

```
public void sortPue() {
    pue_ArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pue::getSpa));
}
```

**The basic one**

```
    List<Pue> listToSort = puep.getPue_ArrayList();

    Pue[] array = listToSort.toArray(new Pue[0]);

    System.out.println("before sorting");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i].getSpa());
    }

    System.out.println("after sorting");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
            if (array[i].getSpa().compareTo(array[j].getSpa()) > 0) {
                Pue temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nAfter performing lexicographical order: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i].getSpa());
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

In case it works and you want an explanation on anything, I can try to explain it in details! I hope it helps.

Comment: One question though. Why did you have to copy the content of Arraylist to a list? Can it not be done inplace?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just did it to use a variable with a more meaningful name, you definetely didn't have to do it!

Comment: Oh it's all good :) I just wanted to see if there any specific reason that approach was taken. I am new to Java so I asked. I immensely appreciate your help and time!!

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, this is probably the source of the problem.

```
    Pue tempPue = pue_ArrayList.get(i);

    pue_ArrayList.set(i, pue_ArrayList.get(j));
    
    pue_ArrayList.set(i, tempPue);
```

So you take out the i'th element, set the i'th element to something else, then set the i'th element back to what it was.  Net result: nothing changed.

Likely that last use of 'i' should be 'j', but I did not analyze this in any detail.

Comment: Hello thank you for your helo. Unfortunately changing indexes didn't resolve my issues.